# Как создать динамический массив переменной длины из LineEdit(ов)?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Пишу программу на с++ в среде Qt, и создал массив состоящий из LineEdit(ов), программа выглядит так:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
QLineEdit *myLine[3];

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
    myLine[i] = new QLineEdit();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(myLine[i]);
}
```

Но мне понадобилось сделать из LineEdit(ов) не статический а динамический массив переменной длины, я попробовал так:

```
int n = 10;
QLineEdit *myLine = new QLineEdit[n];

Теперь код выглядит:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
int n = 10;
QLineEdit *myLine = new QLineEdit[n];

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(myLine[i]);
}
```

Но я почему то получаю следующую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста, как я могу создать такой динамический массив с переменной длиной(мне нужен динамический так как по мере нажатия на кнопку мне нужно будет добавлять новые и новые элементы ,как это сделать? а почему у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему ошибка? потому что в массиве теперь хранятся не указатели на QLineEdit, а собственно они сами (Вы же заметили, что раньше Вам нужно было их создавать, а теперь нет?). Поэтому, вот эту строку

```
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(myLine[i]);
```

перепишите так

```
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(&myLine[i]);
```

и должно заработать.

Если Вам нужен массив, в который можно добавлять/удалять, то в 99% случаев Вам нужен [QVector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html) (если обычный c++, то `std::vector`).

Объявим себе

```
QVectpr<QLineEdit*> myEdits;
```

теперь добавить просто

```
QLineEdit* ed = new QLineEdit;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  myEdits.append(ed);
  ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(ed);
}
```

И в конце не забудьте правильно почистить или сделайте главное окно родителем.

Также сам вектор я бы делал приватной переменной класса.

Comment: @leocoolguy потому что их еще надо создать